# Error 5013 during communication with services required to run MATLAB

Tags: matlab, installation

Does anyone know what `error 5013` actually means and perhaps even how to fix it?

I suspect there is some kind of problem 'talking' to a Windows service (`MathWorksServiceHost`). But that service seems to be running. And that's about what you can see.

**Background**:

New user here. After having installed MATLAB and attempting to run it the very first time,  there is a typical login/registration wizard that asks for e-mail details etc.

Despite having a valid license the wizard somehow doesn't complete successfully.
I didn't think much of it and closed the dialog, to try again later...

But now every attempt to start MATLAB results in the following error:

```
Unexpected error during communication with services required to run MATLAB (error 5013).
To troubleshoot, click "Help".
```

The registration dialog also doesn't appear anymore.
At this point I'm not sure this is related to the failed registration wizard or something else entirely.

The support pages instruct you to kill & restart (and even reinstall) a service called `MathWorksServiceHost`.

https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1815375-why-do-i-receive-error-5013-unable-to-access-services-required-to-run-matlab

But that doesn't help. Those steps effectively only reinstall the same files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just visited the MathWorks `License Center` website, navigated to `Manage Users` and added myself as a new user for my license. Now it seems to work.

Comment: I had the same problem installing a campus license but the License center said I was already added. Eventually I uninstalled Matlab and re-installed by right clicking the installer and choosing "Run as Administrator" which solved the probem for me